# Python - sentence to a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code, which takes a sentence:

```
dimension implies direction implies measurement implies the more and the less
```

and converts it into a dictionary, where the words = key and the value = previous words, but for the first word there is NO value.

It should essentially be:

```
{'and' : 'more'

'dimension' : ''

'direction' : 'implies'

'implies' : 'dimension', 'direction', 'measurement'

'less' : 'the'

'measurement' :'implies'

'more' : 'the'

'the' : 'and', 'implies'}
```

I wrote:

```
def get_previous_words_dict(text):
    words_list = text.split()
    sentence_dict = {}
    for i in range(0,len(words_list)):
        sentence_dict[words_list[i]] = words_list[i-1]
```

BUT it doesn't add the value to the existing value of a key, but rather replaces it, so instead of getting 3 different values for `'implies'` I am only getting 1 value.

Also, instead of assigning NO value to the word dimension, it is assigning it less (since -1).

Comment: I was wondering if adding:
`if i==0:
stenence_dict[words_list[i]] = ''`
would help to get the empty value for first index

Comment: Because you assigning `sentence_dict[words_list[i]] = words_list[i-1]` not appending the the existing value.

You should check for `i == 0` for the first word.

Comment: as a side note: the first loop coulp be replaced with a direct loop over the words

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to do it without a `defaultdict`:

```
text = 'dimension implies direction implies measurement implies the more and the less'
sentence_dict = {}
prev = ''
for word in text.split():
    if word not in sentence_dict:
        sentence_dict[word] = []
    sentence_dict[word].append(prev)
    prev = word

print(sentence_dict)
```

**output**

```
{'and': ['more'], 'direction': ['implies'], 'implies': ['dimension', 'direction', 'measurement'], 'less': ['the'], 'measurement': ['implies'], 'the': ['implies', 'and'], 'dimension': [''], 'more': ['the']}
```

---

Here's a more compact way, using [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
text = 'dimension implies direction implies measurement implies the more and the less'

sentence_dict = {}
prev = ''
for word in text.split():    
    sentence_dict.setdefault(word, []).append(prev)
    prev = word

print(sentence_dict)
```

The previous version is probably a little easier to read.

Comment: so the idea is to just make a new list called prev?

Comment: sorry just a little confused as to what is actually happening in the code

Comment: @Nume: `prev` is just a string. It contains the **prev**ious word. At the start of the loop it contains an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Just split the string in to a list and create another list by offsetting with a prefix empty string, then zip it and create the dictionary by iterating it, PS - use defaultdict initialized with list instead of dictionary because of the possiblity of multiple values for a single key.

```
inp = "dimension implies direction implies measurement implies the more and the less"
l1 = inp.split()
l2 = [""]+l1;
zipped = zip(l1,l2)
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zipped: 
    d[k].append(v)
print d
```

If you don't want to import any thing initialize the dict to consist of empty list then use the same logic

```
inp = "dimension implies direction implies measurement implies the more and the less"
l1 = inp.split()
l2 = [""]+l1;
zipped = zip(l1, l2)
d = {x: [] for x in l1}
for k, v in zipped: 
    d[k].append(v)
print d
```

Comment: we aren't allowed to import anything extra in the function / program.

Comment: I thought about doing an empty space and adding it to the string, but then (with my code) I get " " : "less" in the dictionary as well.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, changed it :)

Comment: FWIW, using unpacking rather than indexing, i.e., `for k, v in zipped: d[k].append(v)` is slightly faster, and a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to import anything then a nifty `reduce` operation together with `slicing` and `zip` (all of these are Python built-ins, requiring no imports) might be a very compact way to do it:

**EDIT**
After having had it pointed out to me that I had misunderstood the problem, fixed it by changing the `zip()` statement.

```
# the string - split it immediately into a list of words
# (some words deleted to make it smaller)
words = "dimension implies direction implies the more and the less".split()

# There is a **lot** going on in this line of code, explanation below.
result = reduce(lambda acc, kv: acc.setdefault(kv[0], []).append(kv[1]) or acc,
                zip(words[1:], words[:-1]), {})
# this was the previous - incorrect - zip()
#                zip(words[1::2], words[0::2]), {})
```

And outputting the result (also **edited**)

```
print result
{'and': ['more'], 'direction': ['implies'], 'implies': ['dimension',
 'direction', 'measurement'], 'less': ['the'], 'measurement':['implies'],
 'the': ['implies', 'and'], 'more': ['the']}
```

For completeness' sake, the old, erroneous, result:

```
print result
{'the': ['and'], 'implies': ['dimension', 'direction', 'measurement'], 'more': ['the']}
```

**A bit of explanation**

After having split the string into a list of words, we can index the individual words as `words[i]`.

**edited** By the problem statement, the keys of the resulting dict are the words following a word, the value being the first word. So we must transform the list of words into a list of combinations of each word with the next word. So the list of `key`'s will be the list [words[1],words[2],words[3],....] and the `values` that go with those are: [words[0], words[1], words[2], ..., words[n-1]].

Using Python `slicing`: `keys = words[1:]` and `values = words[:-1]`

Now we need to create a `dict` of those keys and values, aggregating values into a `list`, if the same key occurs multiple times.

A `dict` has a method `.setdefault(key, value)` which will initialize `key`'s value to `value` if `key` is not in the `dict` yet, otherwise returns the value as it currently is. By default-intializing all values to the empty `list` (`[]`) we can blindly call `.append(...)` on it. That's what this part of the code does:

```
acc.setdefault(key, []).append( value )
```

Then there is `reduce`. A reduce operation reduces (...) a list of values into one. In this case we will reduce a list of `(key, value)` tuples into a `dict` where we accumulated all values to their respective key.

`reduce` takes a callback reduction function and an initial element. The initial element here is the empty dict `{}` - we'll be filling that in as we go along.

The callback reduction function is called repeatedly with two arguments, the accumulator and the next element to add to the accumulation. The function should return the new accumulator.

In this code, the reduction step is basically the addition of the element's value to the list of values for the element's key. (See above - that's what the `.setdefault().append()` does).

All we need is to get a list of `(key, value)` tuples that we need to process. That's where the built-in `zip` appears. `zip` takes two lists and returns a list of tuples of corresponding elements.

Thus:

```
zip(words[1:], words[:-1])
```

produces exactly what we want: the list of all `(key, value)` tuples.

Finally, because the reducing function needs to return the new accumulator, we have to play a trick. `list.append(...)` returns `None`, even though the actual dict has been modified. Thus we cannot return that value as the next accumulator. So we add the construction `or acc` after that.

Because the left-hand side of the logical `or` always evaluates to `None`, which is logically `False` in Python, the right-hand side is always 'evaluated' - in this case the (modified) dict itself. The net result of the `or` evaluates therefore to the modified dict itself, which is exactly what we need to return.

Comment: You appear to have misunderstood the problem statement. _Every_ word in the sentence is a key.

Comment: No worries. Your answer is probably way too advanced for the OP, but hopefully it will benefit future readers.

Comment: That's exactly why I put in the explanation - hopefully someone may benefit from it, thx!

Comment: Almost there! But you're still missing `'dimension': [''],`

Comment: I took the statement "but for the first word there is NO value" (from the problem description) to mean that there should be no value associated with that key, that's why I did not cater for that.

Comment: See the expected output in the question. Sure, it's not proper `dict` syntax, but it does show you what Nume wants.

Comment: I have read this over 8 times now, and I honestly don't understand it - it's probably just too complicated for me because I'm still learning the python basics. However, thank you for the taking the time to write out the explanation, in about a month I'll be starting intermediate python programming so I will be sure to come back to this and see if I can understand it then

Comment: I apologise for the non-proper `dict` syntax. I just started learning `dictionary` with regards to Python just yesterday

Comment: No worries. Just showing off on my behalf (sorry). OTOH, it shows that one (1) single line of Python can do a lot for you! The `reduce` is about the more difficult concepts. But maybe you've learned about the `sum(...)` function already? It sums all values in a list: `sum([1,2,3])` will yield `6`. Behind the scenes that too is a `reduce` operation: convert a list of items (the numbers) into one value, in this case the sum of them. In this code we interpret 'reducing to one value' a bit more creatively :-)